# Парсинг времени Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно пропарсить дату вида  `12:00 = 1200`
Пишу код:

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pattern = "[0-9]+";
        String text = "12:00";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        String a = null;
        while (m.find()) {
            a = text.substring(m.start(), m.end()) + "*";
        }
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

Выводит только `00`, почему не записывает `1200`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не проще использовать `replace()`?

```
String text = "12:00";
String a = text.replace(":", "");
```

А не находит, потому что `m.find()` на первой итерации возвращает Вам `"12"`, Вы присваиваете `a = "12"`. На второй итерации возвращается `"00"`, и Вы перезаписываете `a = "00"`.

Comment: Cпасибо) Как-то не подумал)